# aws cli import access key in json format

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

With the aws cli (version 2) I have created an access key for an iam user, which produces json output. I pipe that output to a file.

Now I would like to import these credentials to my aws cli configuration. aws cli has the `aws configure import` command, but it only accepts a .csv file genereated by the web console.

What is the simplest way to import the access key in json format, short of parsing it and creating the desired csv structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO, not the simplest way but there is this method of [sourcing external program](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-sourcing-external.html) to read the creds in json format.

Comment: That is actually pretty close to what I need, since the external programm is expected to generate the json that I already have. So a simple `cat creds.json` in the config should do the trick.